# PHP SELECT * FROM not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to query data from a table using the following script:

```
//connect file
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//connect file included above - ECHO tested and it is connected as $conn

$sql = "SELECT * FROM userInfo";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$results) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit;
} else {
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

UPDATE --

It now no longer tries to throw an error and seems to go to the `else` section; however, no echo - and the spelling is correct this time and the column is filled.

Comment: Find out why your query is failing http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  instead of a custom error text-based message. You also don't have an `else` so do `else { echo "there's info in here, now I just need to loop over the results."; }`

Comment: Is the example right? Because you have: `$results = $conn->query($sql);` but then in the 'if' statement, you are checking `!$result` - not `$!results`. `$result` variable is not assigned/initialized.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No messsage comes up when I change that line to `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);`  it shows "Errormessage: "

Comment: that's because it should read as `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);` ;-)

Comment: then tell us what error you get ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- Updating the spelling now treats it as if it is functioning; however, when I try and echo $row['username'] it does not echo anything - or any errors

Comment: @jjczopek good catch!! error reporting would have spotted that unassigned variable/typo. To OP Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code.

Comment: can you tell me... for the life of me, why this question was closed with that link? and what it has to do with `bind_param() error`?! Edit: I've reopened the question and it also had 2 reopen votes. @yourcommonsense, don't do that. Have some "common sense" will ya?

Comment: Do you really have a column named `username` in `userInfo` table?

Comment: `echo $row['username'];` you need a `while` loop for that.

Comment: @Rahul yes I do. 'username' 'password' 'email' 'dob' are my columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["username"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

This now returns results. Thank you @Fred -ii- especially for your help on this.

Also thanks @jjczopek for the error checking advice!

Comment: Thank for giving credit to me but I think much help have been offered by @Fred -ii-  and the other guy you have already named in answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for catching that - thanks for your check on the column names too